# how to get exactly element of 1st row of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
Charlie,3,2,5
```

I did this:

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as csvfile:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    print(','.join(row))
```

and it printed:

name,AGATC,AATG,TATC

name,AGATC,AATG,TATC

name,AGATC,AATG,TATC

I need to get access to AGATC AATG TATC
i mean i have job to do with seperetly AGATC, AATG, TATC

---

sorry this is my first question here so i little confused what is what
thank you for answer

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: i did this: with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as csvfile:                                                                      
                      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)   and i want you help what to do next to for example print AGATC, AATC, TATC

Comment: A dictionary doesn't have any "rows". And what you show here is not a python dictionary anyway.

Comment: @Mirzohid Please [edit] your question to show that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your OP is the contents of csv file, you just need:

```
reader.fieldnames
```

or maybe

```
reader.fieldnames[1:]
```

To be specific, you are looking for the first row in the csv file, which is usually the header row.  When you access the data rows with the Dict reader, you will get the data, with the keys provided by the header row.

```
for x in reader:
     print (x)
```

Will show you the rows of data, as OrderedDicts:

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'Alice'), ('AGATC', '2'), ('AATG', '8'), ('TATC', '3')])
OrderedDict([('name', 'Bob'), ('AGATC', '4'), ('AATG', '1'), ('TATC', '5')])
OrderedDict([('name', 'Charlie'), ('AGATC', '3'), ('AATG', '2'), ('TATC', '5')])
```

Comment: wow thank you, it printed   ['AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC']   how I get AGATC for example

Comment: Using a `slice` like that, you'll get a list.  if you want the single element, just use `reader.fieldnames[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this reader object to list. See into the below code

```
import csv

with open("sample.csv", "r") as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    print(list(reader))
```

Comment: it really helped but it doesn't gives me the rist row